# how to calculate a percentage of evolution or trend over several years with R?

Tags: r, statistics

I need to calculate a percentage change over 4 years per km. is there a function that would allow this calculation ?

```
df <- data.frame(km = c(100:111), 
                 A2012 = c(12:23), 
                 A2013 = c(14,25), 
                 A2014 =  c(10,21), 
                 A2015  = c(18, 29),
                 Coef_Evol="?")
```

Comment: What is the algorithm, what is the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: In addition to what @jogo says, note that requesting functions/packages etc. is also outside the scope of this site

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Do you need this year over year or just the first and last year?

Comment: All km, I have a temperature record. I would like to know the global trend of this evolution. It can take the form of a percentage or an index.
Sorry for this function request, this is not the purpose. I am looking for a solution rather than a miracle function.

Tell me if it's still not clear.

I made the calculation:
(Finalvalue-StartValue) / StartValue
but the starting value is not necessarily a basic standard, so the result does not necessarily sum up the overall trend.

Comment: @Loisau Please put this additional information in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56457617/edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing as 1 number to account for the overall changes over time. So I think you can either put the calculation you already used: `(Finalvalue - StartValue) / StartValue)` or you can create an additional `df2` that shows the percentage change year over year:

```
df <- data.frame(km = c(100:111), 
                 A2012 = c(12:23), 
                 A2013 = c(14,25), 
                 A2014 =  c(10,21), 
                 A2015  = c(18, 29))
df
    km A2012 A2013 A2014 A2015
1  100    12    14    10    18
2  101    13    25    21    29
3  102    14    14    10    18
4  103    15    25    21    29
5  104    16    14    10    18
6  105    17    25    21    29
7  106    18    14    10    18
8  107    19    25    21    29
9  108    20    14    10    18
10 109    21    25    21    29
11 110    22    14    10    18
12 111    23    25    21    29
df2 <- data.frame(df[1], NA * df[2], 100 * (df[-(1:2)] / df[-c(1, ncol(df))] - 1))
df2
    km A2012      A2013     A2014    A2015
1  100    NA  16.666667 -28.57143 80.00000
2  101    NA  92.307692 -16.00000 38.09524
3  102    NA   0.000000 -28.57143 80.00000
4  103    NA  66.666667 -16.00000 38.09524
5  104    NA -12.500000 -28.57143 80.00000
6  105    NA  47.058824 -16.00000 38.09524
7  106    NA -22.222222 -28.57143 80.00000
8  107    NA  31.578947 -16.00000 38.09524
9  108    NA -30.000000 -28.57143 80.00000
10 109    NA  19.047619 -16.00000 38.09524
11 110    NA -36.363636 -28.57143 80.00000
12 111    NA   8.695652 -16.00000 38.09524
```

Perhaps you can then add an additional column that shows the average percentage change...